# How to style RecyclerView like google CardView

Tags: listview, android-recyclerview

Can somebody tell me how to achieve this kind of View? It looks like it is one CardView which has inside a recyclerView? Thanks for help.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pSpl.png

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to take a stab at this:
I'm assuming you want to make a recycler view look like the photo you have linked. Each row within the recycler view can be customized to your liking by loading a custom layout for each row via a custom class extending RecyclerView.ViewHolder. Then in your recyclerAdapter, override oncreateViewHolder and instead of using the super call, you just return an instance of your custom view holder!!

```
  class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView title;

    public myViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_studySpot);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

And for your recyclerView:

```
@Override
public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_layout, parent, false);
    return new myViewHolder(view);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't explain how to make the entire RecyclerView look like an CardView, but it is for customizing each row. Not what the question is about.